# Does react-native support react 16?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When trying `react-native init myproject` I am getting `16.0.0-alpha.5` as a react dependency

When installing react@16 I am getting the following warning:

`UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0`

**Note:** Using react-native v0.49.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `react-native init`, it initialize the project with the last react version working with it.  React has always a few steps of development ahead of React native, because React Native is built with React. So you will have the latest react version included in the react native init project in a few weeks.

Comment: @Iocropulenton Did my answer help you ?